# Why does adding a bigint column to a select double my query execution time?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I am running postgresql 14.4.

I have two tables, `stocks_buys` and `stocks_quotes`. Quotes contains the daily closing amount for a security while Buys constitute a particular transaction/contract with total amount and the quantity of shares. Their schemas are as follows:

```rb
create_table "stocks_buys", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "security_id", null: false                                                                                                                        
  t.integer "total_cents", default: 0, null: false                                                                                                           
  t.decimal "quantity", precision: 8, scale: 2, default: "0.0"                                                                                               
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false                                                                                                                       
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false                                                                                                                       
  t.date "date"
  t.bigint "account_id"                                                                                                                                      
  t.decimal "shares_not_sold", precision: 8, scale: 2, default: "0.0"                                                                                        
  t.index ["account_id"], name: "index_stocks_buys_on_account_id"                                                                                            
  t.index ["date"], name: "index_stocks_buys_on_date"                                                                                                        
  t.index ["security_id"], name: "index_stocks_buys_on_security_id"                                                                                          
end  

create_table "stocks_quotes", force: :cascade do |t|                                                                                                         
  t.bigint "security_id"                                                                                                                                     
  t.date "date"                                                                                                                                              
  t.datetime "created_at", default: -> { "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" }, null: false                                                                                  
  t.datetime "updated_at", default: -> { "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" }, null: false                                                                                  
  t.bigint "close_cents"                                                                                                                                           
  t.index ["date"], name: "index_stocks_quotes_on_date"                                                                                                      
  t.index ["security_id", "date"], name: "index_stocks_quotes_on_security_id_and_date", unique: true                                                         
  t.index ["security_id"], name: "index_stocks_quotes_on_security_id"                                                                                        
end
```

The query I am trying to create is to join these two tables together and show all the quote amounts for each contract from purchase date to now.

My current query looks like the following:

```sql
SELECT 
  "stocks_buys"."id" as "buy_id",                                                                                                                              
  "stocks_buys"."security_id",                                                                                                                                 
  "stocks_buys"."account_id",                                                                                                                                  
  "stocks_buys"."shares_not_sold" as "quantity",                                                                                                               
  "stocks_quotes"."date" as "date",                                                                                                                            
  "stocks_buys"."total_cents" as "cost_basis_total_cents",                                                                                                     
  "stocks_quotes"."close_cents",
  "stocks_buys"."quantity" as "cost_basis_quantity"                                                                                                            
FROM "stocks_buys"                                                                                                                                             
INNER JOIN "stocks_quotes" 
    on "stocks_quotes"."security_id" = "stocks_buys"."security_id"
   AND "stocks_quotes"."date" >= "stocks_buys"."date"                 
WHERE "stocks_buys"."shares_not_sold" > 0
```

With around 43k quotes and 430 buys this query takes about 60-70ms.

Running explain on the query returns:

```
                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Join  (cost=2060.54..6186.27 rows=88844 width=48) (actual time=25.060..54.465 rows=29726 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (stocks_buys.security_id = stocks_quotes.security_id)
   Join Filter: (stocks_quotes.date >= stocks_buys.date)
   Rows Removed by Join Filter: 344962
   Buffers: shared hit=1130
   ->  Seq Scan on stocks_buys  (cost=0.00..36.36 rows=115 width=40) (actual time=0.047..0.198 rows=115 loops=1)
         Filter: (shares_not_sold > '0'::numeric)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 314         Buffers: shared hit=31   ->  Hash  (cost=1526.35..1526.35 rows=42735 width=20) (actual time=24.983..24.984 rows=42735 loops=1)
         Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2850kB
         Buffers: shared hit=1099
         ->  Seq Scan on stocks_quotes  (cost=0.00..1526.35 rows=42735 width=20) (actual time=0.007..13.217 rows=42735 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=1099
 Planning Time: 0.443 ms
 Execution Time: 56.382 ms
(16 rows)

Time: 57.790 ms
```

However, the problem I am having is that if I remove the `close_cents` column from the select, the time it takes to run gets cut to almost a third of the original with a completely different query plan. When I explain on the new query without `close_cents` I get:

```
                                                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                                                   
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.41..5527.21 rows=88302 width=40) (actual time=0.119..15.750 rows=29726 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=568
   ->  Seq Scan on stocks_buys  (cost=0.00..36.36 rows=114 width=40) (actual time=0.067..0.355 rows=115 loops=1)
         Filter: (shares_not_sold > '0'::numeric)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 314
         Buffers: shared hit=31
   ->  Index Only Scan using index_stocks_quotes_on_security_id_and_date on stocks_quotes  (cost=0.41..36.30 rows=1187 width=12) (actual time=0.008..0.068 rows=258 loops=115)
         Index Cond: ((security_id = stocks_buys.security_id) AND (date >= stocks_buys.date))
         Heap Fetches: 0
         Buffers: shared hit=537
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=3
 Planning Time: 0.822 ms
 Execution Time: 18.706 ms
(14 rows)
```

If I try `SET enable_seqscan = OFF;` to try and force Postgres to use indexes when including `close_cents` it still doesn't want to use the `index_stocks_quotes_on_security_id_and_date` index.

```
 Merge Join  (cost=0.56..6958.49 rows=88912 width=48) (actual time=0.281..76.936 rows=29726 loops=1)
   Merge Cond: (stocks_buys.security_id = stocks_quotes.security_id)
   Join Filter: (stocks_quotes.date >= stocks_buys.date)
   Rows Removed by Join Filter: 344962
   Buffers: shared hit=732
   ->  Index Scan using index_stocks_buys_on_security_id on stocks_buys  (cost=0.27..148.00 rows=115 width=40) (actual time=0.180..0.427 rows=115 loops=1)         Filter: (shares_not_sold > '0'::numeric)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 314         Buffers: shared hit=78
   ->  Materialize  (cost=0.29..2249.14 rows=42735 width=20) (actual time=0.087..34.198 rows=383051 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=654
         ->  Index Scan using index_stocks_quotes_on_security_id on stocks_quotes  (cost=0.29..2142.31 rows=42735 width=20) (actual time=0.076..9.197 rows=42735 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=654
 Planning Time: 0.708 ms
 Execution Time: 78.437 ms
```

I originally had close_cents as a decimal(I was still storing as cents but just wanted more precision, calm down) and changed it to a bigint to see if that helped. It didn't really.

So what gives? Why would adding this column to the select, which isn't used in the join or where, cause such a drastic slowdown? Is there something I can do not make it so slow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The table `stock_quotes` has the index `t.index ["security_id", "date"]` that happens to serve for searches and also includes the columns in the select list. That's why it uses this index instead of a `Seq Scan` when you remove the column `close_cents`.

You can try creating a "covering index" for the original query as:

```
create index ix1 on stock_quotes (security_id, date) include (close_cents);
```

Try creating this index and retrieving the new plan for the original query.